# Chrome not live reloading when LESS partials are edited

Tags: css, google-chrome, less, gulp, gulp-less

I have a project where I'm using LESS as my CSS pre-processor and Gulp as my build tool. I have a folder structure as follows:

- stylesheets
- > less
- >> partials
- >>>_colours.less
- >> index.less

My `index.less` file looks like this:

```
@import "partials/_colours";

.red { color: @colour; font-size: 12em; }
```

My `_colours.less` file looks like this:

```
@colour: red;
```

And my `gulpfile.js` looks like this (simplified, removed error handling)

```
var lessFiles = ['stylesheets/less/**/*.less', '!stylesheets/less/partials/*.less'];

gulp.task('less:compile', function() {
    return gulp.src(lessFiles)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("maps", {includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '../less'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('stylesheets'));
});

gulp.task('less:watch', ['less:compile'], function() {
    return gulp.watch(lessFiles[0], ['less:compile']);
});
```

When I run `gulp less:watch` everything compilles and I get an `index.css` file (with source maps) in my stylesheets directory that I can take to Chrome and wire up for live editing.

If I edit the `index.less` file in the Chrome editor and save, I get an instant reload. However, if I change the value of the `@color` variable in `_colours.less` I don't see the change until I reload the window.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Chrome 43.

Comment: Not a bug, this is expceted behabiour. Chrome will not reload the stylesheet automatically and will not detect file changes.

Comment: When you say "Chrome will not reload the stylesheet automatically and will not detect file changes.", you're talking about the _colours.less file, right?

Comment: Yes, chrome has no way of knowing the file has changed.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Closest thing I could find: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors.

But in all honesty this is due to the HTTP/1.1 being request-response and this being carried over to HTML/CSS. Additionally Chrome blocks AJAX/XMLHTTPRequests without the same origin and from/to the file:// protocol.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help Fabian. I'll wait a couple days before I close this question in case anyone has anything more they wish to share.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is expected behaviour cause why should it work for `index.less` and not for `_colours.less`.

Of course you should make sure that saving `_colours.less` indeed run your compile task. (Less errors should stop / break the watch task too)

Some older and newer issues with Chrome autoreload CSS are described here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=273384

When adding your Network Mappings make sure that your workspace includes your `stylsheets`  and not only `stylsheets/less`.

Comment: I can confirm that saving the _colours.less file causes the compiler task to trigger. My workspace not only includes the stylesheets/less folder, but the entire project folder. What I don't get is, the compiler task changes the index.less file after the _colours.less file is updated, so in theory index.css would also be updated which should should trigger a reload, right? It seems that folks on the discussion thread you directed me to also have similar problems once using @import statements.